# Is there any Windows API or Microsoft Service to programmatically know if my Windows Installation is the latest version?

Tags: c#, windows-update

I'm creating a guided troubleshooting so the users can fix configuration issues for an external device. One of the steps for the wizard is to make sure the users has the latest windows version installed on their system.

So, my problem is: is there a way to programmatically (Windows API, Microsoft Webservice, ...) determine if the Windows installation is the latest Windows version, with latest update and/or service pack installed?

I need to know that no matter if users are running Win 7, Win 8.1 or Win 10.

In other words, I have an OSInfo class and I need to have a property like:

`OSInfo.IsLatestVersion`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What constitutes "latest version," specifically?  All the latest patches?

Comment: You must realize that there are workstations configured to get updates from a corporate WSUS server instead of directly from Microsoft.  So a Microsoft-provided webservice is quite out of the question, as it might tell users they are missing updates which corporate policy forbids them to install.  The Windows Update APIs can tell you if your update server (whether the main MS one or a site WSUS) has any available updates that the local PC hasn't yet installed.

Comment: Then your question boils down to "List available Windows Updates" possibly with a requirement to tell what category they are: Service Pack/Rollup, Critical Security, or Feature.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt, you answers really give me some ideas and directions.